# Javascript Create new Number wıth own properties

Tags: javascript, object, numbers, primitive

I want create new number object with own properties from  Number.
But when assign a number value to my variable, my variable turn to Number(primitive wrapper object).and loss own properties.How can I prevent this?
**Example**

```js
class Fnumber extends Number {
  value = 0;
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint === 'object') {
      return this;
    }
    return this.value;
  };
  //I don't want use Number.prototype.add method because this effect all Number values.
  add = function(...v) {
    this.value += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce((o, v) => o + v)
  }
}
var nmbr = new Fnumber();
nmbr.add(4, 2, 4);
console.log(nmbr); //return a Object
console.log(nmbr + 4); //return 14 is number
nmbr = 14;
console.log(nmbr); //return not a Object its Primative number value
console.log(nmbr + 4); //return 14 a number
nmbr.add(4, 2, 4); //raise error.
```

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do? Why should a *number literal* give you some sort of custom object in the line `nmbr = 14`?

Comment: you reassign 14 (which is just a number) to nmbr , it has no add function

Comment: I want to change this.value when assign to any number value. I dont want lost my own properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution indirectly.

```
class Fnumber extends Number {
value = 0;
add(...v) {
   this.value += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce((o, v) => o + v)
}
}
//temğrary variable description
var _nmbr=new Fnumber();
//Define nmbr variable in global scobe
Object.defineProperty(window,"nmbr",{
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get() { return _nmbr; },
    set(val) { if (typeof val=="number")_nmbr.value=val; }
});
nmbr=4;
console.log(nmbr+2);//output 6
//still nmbr variable is object,because assigned value  to 
_nmbr.value with above set method
nmbr.add(4, 2, 4);
console.log(nmbr+2);//output 16
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing `nmbr = 14` you assign `14` to `nmbr`, you are not changing the `nmbr.value`, you are overwriting the object. Instead call `add` and use `nmbr.value` when needed.

```js
class Fnumber extends Number {
  value = 0;

  add(...v) {
    this.value += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce((o, v) => o + v)
  }
}
var nmbr = new Fnumber();
nmbr.add(4, 2, 4);
console.log(nmbr.value);
nmbr.add(5);
console.log(nmbr.value);

nmbr.value = 25; // assign a value to nmbr.value
console.log(nmbr.value);
```

If you are not planning on reassigning the object, a good practice is to use `const` instead of `var`, see the error below.

```js
class Fnumber extends Number {};
const nmbr = new Fnumber();
nmbr = 14;
```

Comment: My variable can be assigned a number, but I don't want object properties to be lost
Number constructor hasownprotertıes as Number.prototype.toFixed. I want to same.

Comment: @CemFrt assign a value to `nmbr.value` (see answer update)